# Закрытие окна Fancybox

Tags: html, css, jquery, fancybox, modal

Есть кнопка при нажатии на которую открывается fancybox с формой, после заполнения формы и нажатия на кнопку отправить хочу что-бы это окно автоматически закрылось и открылось еще одно с текстом "что письмо успешно отправлено" и спустя пару секунд что-бы оно исчезало, или при  нажатии вне области окна.

Сейчас открывается alert();

```
$("form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            $('#alert-massage').fadeIn(500);
            alert("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });

<div id="modal">
    <div class="modal__wrap">
        <div class="modal__title">
            Write me
        </div>
        <form >
            <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
            <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="kylun-Serg">
            <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="kylun1serg@gmail.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="popup-form">
            <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Name"   required>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name = "E-mail"required>
            <input type="phone" placeholder="Phone" name = "Phone">
            <textarea placeholder="Massage" name="Massage"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">
            Send
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```